# IIS PHP connect to MSSQL using Windows Authentication and end-user identity

Tags: php, sql-server, active-directory, windows-authentication

We are on-premises, windows server running PHP behind IIS and a SQL Server Cluster on some other server.

Is there a way to authenticate the SQL requests from our PHP application with the end-users identity?

To be more clear: Setting up IIS with Windows Authentication is working, as well as authenticating the PHP Process (Application Pool in IIS) against our SQL Server via AD is done and done.
What we want to achieve (rather our Security Team) is to use the end-users identity for the requests.
So that we can grant permissions to AD users/groups in the SQL Server to specific roles instead of just the PHP process.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would that be necessary or useful? Then users, if they're savvy, could make direct connections to the database and bypass any business logic in your application. My organisation got rid of all that as it was a security and data integrity risk, and too much hassle to maintain as well. Let the application handle authorisation to perform certain  actions or access certain data, and do validation of changes. And then just connect to sql with a generic identity as you do now. Don't give end users direct access to any sql server. That would be my advice, anyway.

Comment: Besides, looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-windows-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16 it it seems to suggest it isn't possible to connect with the end user's identity, although using impersonation in IIS might work possibly (although that in itself may introduce other complications to your site that you would rather avoid)

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a seriously bad idea.

Comment: What worries me even more is that this suggestion to make security more difficult to regulate appears to have come from some people described as a "security" team...

Comment: You need to set up impersonation in IIS, and then you need to set up either Constrained Delegation or Resource-Based CD, which means you need to involve your IT department to get Active Directory set up correctly.

Comment: I know that this is not the best solution (even sh**ty), but sometimes you have regulations that just exist and you can't change that..., even if they are bad :(
thanks @Charlieface I will try that.